# HTML generated by Extent Report is not showing any data, what could be wrong?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports

Hi I am trying to create report through Extent Report; the code gives no error and runs successfully but the html report generated is blank. Can anyone please help below is my code
Also attaching my report sample - [Report Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vTZe.jpg)

```
public class VerifyLoginPageWithReport 
{

    WebDriver driver;
    String email = DataProviderFactory.getExcel().getData(0, 0, 0);
    String pass = DataProviderFactory.getExcel().getData(0, 0, 1);

    ExtentReports report;
    ExtentTest logger;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() 
    {
    report = new ExtentReports("\\Reports\\LoginPageReport.html", true);
    // Start the test using the ExtentTest class object
    logger = report.startTest("VerifyLoginPage", "This page will verify signout link");
    // passing browser type and url
    driver = BrowserFactory.getBrowser("chrome");
    driver.get(DataProviderFactory.getConfig().getApplicationUrl());
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Application is up and running");
    }

    @Test
    public void testHomePage()
    {    
    // initialize the home page
    HomePage home = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
    String title = home.getApplicationTitle();
    // verifying the homepage
    Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("Online Shopping"));
    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "HomePage Loaded and verified");
    home.clickOnSignInLink();
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Sign In link clicked");
    // Initialzing login page
    LoginPage login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
    // passing credentials
    login.loginApplication(email, pass);
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Login to application");
    // Verifying the signoutlink
    login.verifySignOutLink();
    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Signout link verifed");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown()
    {
    BrowserFactory.closeBrowser(driver);
    report.endTest(logger);
    report.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test has no reporter attached.  What version of Extent Reports are you running?  I'm guessing it's 2.x?  If so, install the 3.x community version and follow its examples.

Comment: Hi Bill, I am using  2.41.0 with maven dependency<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I suggest that you [download version 3 from here](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/)